# FOSUserBundle: username vs usernameCanonical

Tags: php, symfony

Why does the FOSUserBundle User entity have two properties for a username (and other fields)?

```
/**
 * @var string
 */
protected $username;

/**
 * @var string
 */
protected $usernameCanonical;
```

I've read the docs, browsed the source code, and tried to search for information, and I can't find out why it exists.  It seems to always store the same values.  I'm sure there is a good reason, can someone fill me in?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Canonical fields get lowercased before comparison or search — to make sure there are no duplicates with the same value but with different case like `Test@test.org` and `test@test.org`.

Comment: But if your table's collation is set to some case insensitive value (like `utf8_unicode_ci`), does it really matter?

Comment: @pikachu0, not all RDBMSes are case-insensitive. For instance, PostgreSQL — the RDBMS I use — is case-sensitive by default.

Comment: Yes, that's why I said *if* it was case insensitive. :)

Comment: @pikachu0 the purpose of an ORM is to be as database agnostic as possible, so there no sense in doing such assumption as "if the collation is set to..."

Comment: I have to give a +1 to Ninj reply ;)